# Javascript tabbing system

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

```js
var editor;
window.addEventListener('load',function () {

var textarea = document.getElementById("editor");
editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "htmlmixed",
  tabSize: 3,
  value: 'console.log("Hello, World");',
  theme: 'monokai',
});
})
window.addEventListener('load',function () {
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tab1').css('background-color', '#272822');
  var active = 'tab1';
  var html_code = '//Html code goes here';
  var css_code = '//Css code goes here';
  var js_code = '//Js code goes here';
  $("#tab1").trigger('click');
  //Tab system
  $('.tab').click(function() {
    var currentvalue = editor.getValue();
    if (currentvalue != "") {
      if (active == "tab1") {
        html_code = currentvalue;
      } else if (active == "tab2") {
        css_code = currentvalue;
      } else if (active == "tab3") {
        js_code = currentvalue;
      }
    }

    active = $(this).attr("id");
    if (active == "tab1") {
      editor.setValue(html_code);
    } else if (active == "tab2") {
      editor.setValue(css_code);
    } else if (active == "tab3") {
      editor.setValue(js_code);
    }
    $('.tab').css('background-color', '#352a2aa9');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#272822');
  })

  $('.compile').click(function () {
      alert(html_code + js_code + css_code);
  })
})
})
```

```css
.tabs {
    margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
}

.tab {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #352a2aa9;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/theme/monokai.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.55.0/addon/hint/show-hint.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="code-editor">
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab" id="tab1">
                    index.html
                </div>
                <div class="tab" id="tab2">
                    index.css
                </div>
                <div class="tab" id="tab3">
                    index.js
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="compile">submit</button>
```

I'm trying to make a tab system for my code editor.
For example, I have 3 tabs, HTML tab CSS tab, and a javascript tab.
The problem is when I try to switch tabs again, the HTML gets the CSS tab value and the js tab gets the CSS value as well.
here is my code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){
        $('#tab1').css('background-color','#272822');
        var active = 'tab1';
        var html_code = '//Html code goes here';
        var css_code = '//Css code goes here';
        var js_code = '//Js code goes here';
        check_tab();
        $("#tab1").trigger('click');
        //Tab system
        $('.tab').click(function(){
            $('.tab').css('background-color','#352a2aa9');
            $(this).css('background-color','#272822');
            $(this).css('color','white');

            if (this.id == 'tab2' && active == 'tab1') {
                html_code = editor.getValue();
                if(css_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab2';
                    editor.setValue(css_code);
                }
                           
            } 
            if (this.id == 'tab3' && active == 'tab2') {
                css_code = editor.getValue();
                if(js_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab3';
                    editor.setValue(js_code);
                } 
            }     
            if (this.id == 'tab2' && active == 'tab3') {
                js_code = editor.getValue();
                if(css_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab2';
                    editor.setValue(css_code);
                }
            }  
            if (this.id == 'tab1' && active == 'tab3') {
                js_code = editor.getValue();
                if(html_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab1';
                    editor.setValue(html_code);
                }
            }  

            if (this.id == 'tab1' && active == 'tab2') {
                css_code = editor.getValue();
                if(html_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab1';
                    editor.setValue(html_code);
                }
            }

            if (this.id == 'tab2' && active == 'tab1') {
                if(css_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab2';
                    editor.setValue(css_code);
                }
            }
            if (this.id == 'tab3' && active == 'tab1') {
                html_code = editor.getValue();
                if(js_code !== undefined){
                    active = 'tab3';
                    editor.setValue(js_code);
                }
            }
            check_tab();
        })

        function check_tab(){
            if(active == 'tab1'){
                editor.on('change',function (editor) {
                    html_code = editor.getValue();
                })
            }
            if(active == 'tab2'){
                editor.on('change',function (editor) {
                    css_code = editor.getValue();
                })
            }
            if(active == 'tab3'){
                editor.on('change',function (editor) {
                    js_code = editor.getValue();
                })
            }
        }
```

I'm working with CodeMirror to display the code editor.
I will add code if the question is lacking info.
Thanks in advance!
HTML code:

```
<div class="code-editor">
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab" id="tab1">
                    index.html
                </div>
                <div class="tab" id="tab2">
                    index.css
                </div>
                <div class="tab" id="tab3">
                    index.js
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
```

The problem is when I click the submit button, it brings the old values of the variables, it only changes the variables values if I switch tabs.

Comment: Please consider giving us your html and css code, it will be much easier to help you that way.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen done.

Comment: What does `editor` refer to in your code?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen to the code mirror editor, its the textarea

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen can you add a way to take the live value of each tab?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It doesn't switch the values of the variables until you switch tabs

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added a snippet + the problem I am facing with your code

Answer (score 1):

I made it a bit more simple, but it could be improved more, but i want you to understand the changes to take a loot at the demo below.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var editor;
  var textarea = document.getElementById("editor");
  editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "htmlmixed"
  });

  $('#tab1').css('background-color', '#272822');
  var active = 'tab1';
  var html_code = '//Html code goes here';
  var css_code = '//Css code goes here';
  var js_code = '//Js code goes here';
  //Tab system
  $('.tab').click(function() {
    var currentvalue = editor.getValue();
    if (currentvalue != "") {
      if (active == "tab1") {
        html_code = currentvalue;
      } else if (active == "tab2") {
        css_code = currentvalue;
      } else if (active == "tab3") {
        js_code = currentvalue;
      }
    } else {
      editor.setValue(html_code)
    }

    active = $(this).attr("id");
    if (active == "tab1") {
      editor.setValue(html_code);
    } else if (active == "tab2") {
      editor.setValue(css_code);
    } else if (active == "tab3") {
      editor.setValue(js_code);
    }
    $('.tab').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#272822');
  })
  
  $("#tab1").trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<link href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="code-editor">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab" id="tab1">
      index.html
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab2">
      index.css
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab3">
      index.js
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @עילאיאלמלם No problem

Comment: Hey, but how can i get the live value of the current tab? tysm!

Comment: It doesn't switch the values of the variables until you switch tabs

Comment: You're here bro?